# Moving a hard-drive that has Linux and Windows 7 installed

Tags: linux, windows-7, hard-drive

My memory is that if one removes a hard-drive running Windows and re-installs it in another computer it immediately craps-out, until one can go through Microsoft to reauthorize it (I hope this makes sense — I haven't used Windows much for years).

If this is correct, would the same apply to a hard-drive dual-booting Linux and Windows 7?

Comment: "craps-out" - you mean Windows becomes unactivated ?

Comment: If the hardware is substantially the same, the PC should boot to both through grub. That said, I'd suggest salvaging data and listing applications, then removing all partitions, formatting and using the HDD as a second drive. What use is Win7, except to vintage computer users (I admit to fondness for Atari XL's ad ST's, and ZX-81)? **If** the Ubuntu partition is up-to-date, it *might* be worth salvaging as a whole OS.

Comment: Many years ago I tried (perhaps twice?) to move a hard-drive running Windows to another computer without success — my memory is that the computer simply behaved as if there was no operating system present.

My interest — aside from simple curiosity — is that occasionally I find the Simply Accounting program useful, and so I keep it installed on one of my second-string computers; the computer in question runs Windows 7, either because it was given to me, or because I find the installation easy, or because I find the later versions of Windows increasingly obnoxious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your computer is old enough to run Windows 7.  Newer computers will not likely allow
Windows 7 to install.

Microsoft has asked / encouraged Manufacturers not to allow Windows CPU (BIOS and possibly chipset as well) to run Windows 7.

So all you can do is take your chances.

Also, if you do get a newer computer, it will now come with Windows 11, and you can run Windows 7 and Linux as virtual machines.

Comment: You might be able to install Windows 7 on systems with newer processors, but you won't be able to update Windows 7 since Microsoft put in compatibility blockers.  I believe any processor newer than 7th generation Intel Core processors (and AMD's equivalent Bristol Ridge or Ryzen) makes it impossible to update Windows 7.  **Windows 7 of course stop receiving updates in 2020.** Newer processors are dropping support for older revisions of standards like Wi-Fi, which means it won't be possible to install Windows 7 on a system with a motherboard with Wi-Fi 7 capability.

Comment: Almost by definition, any of my computers are 'older'! But yes, I suppose Windows 7 will age out someday. When I use Windows, I carefully avoid going on-line, so Wi-Fi support would never be a problem.

I know nothing about virtual machines, so it's probably time I learn ... (brief pause, to imagine all the things I *should* be learning!)

The next time I'm tearing down a computer I'll just swap a hard-drive and see what happens — even though the results will only be valid for that particular case!

Comment: Old machines do not run on new hardware, so best to get some learning on virtual machines as that will be necessary to run old machines on new operating systems.